# How to change VSTS contribution properties from build task execution time

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to change the height of "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-section" contribution point when loading the summary page itself. Currently these values are set to fixed size in extension manifest resulting excess white space when there is no information to display as summary. I cannot manipulate this value from html level since the summary page is generated inside an iFrame element. The size of the iFrame is decided in an upper level DIV element. Is there a way to do this from VSS.SDK?

**Extension point**

```
    {
        "id": "my-build-status-section",
        "type": "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-section",
        "description": "My Summary",
        "targets": [
            ".build-info-tab",
            "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-summary-tab"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "My Summary Section",
            "uri": "TestExtension/MyBuildSummary.html",
            "order": 20,
            "height": 1200,
            "width": 450
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this via [resize()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/core-sdk#method_resize) method in Core SDK.

First, remove the `"height": 1200,` section from the contribution preperties.

And then, call the resize() method in your html page. For example, resize the width to 450 and height to 900:

```
VSS.resize(450,900);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Eddie, I did the changes as you suggested and called the resize() before calling VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded(), still page is not changed. Also resize method doesn't accept height and width parameters. - Thanks.

Comment: @BandR Did you remove the height  from the property? It works at my side.

Comment: And the method can  accept the parameter. If you didn't  specify the parameter,  it will use the  default scroll value. For height, it is 150.

Comment: Initially I was using the VSS.SDK with Rest Version: 2.2, I tried with the latest version (version 2.3)  and it worked. Thanks very much for the support Eddie.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify **“height”:”auto”** value in properties, then the height will according to the actual content of custom result summary.

For this way, the height limit is 150px, you can add overflow to visible style to body element of your page (style="overflow: visible;") in order to the content height is larger than 150px.

Comment: It doesn't get expand more than 150px, resulting some section of the summary page cropped out.

Comment: Based on my test, the result is the same to you. I tried to change height through JavaScript, failed. You can add style="overflow:visible;" to deal with this issue.

Comment: Thanks Starain, I can see scroll bars when I add the style as you suggested. Did you get the same issue?